# How to read SQLite EXPLAIN

Tags: sqlite

I'm writing an on-line small SQL guide and I'm trying to explain the indexes. The table is the follow:

```
    CREATE TABLE fdic (id integer primary key autoincrement,
                       primitive text,
                       v text,
                       v_a text)
```

With around 3M rows. The column v contains some words but with capital and diacritical charachters, v_a contains the same word but lower case and with the diacritical charachters replaced. The column v_a is indexed (not unique) meanwhile the column v is not indexed.
So I execute this query:

```
SELECT a.v originale,b.v contrario
FROM fdic a
INNER JOIN fdic b ON a.v_a=rev(b.v_a) 
WHERE length(a.v_a)>3 
AND a.v_a<>rev(a.v_a)
```

where **rev()** is mine function  that reverses the string. It does not work with multybyte charachters, but I don't want slow it down, they have to use it only with the column v_a. This query just finds the words that exist reading from left to right and from right to left, but are not palindrome (the last condition of the `WHERE`). Execution time is 2.7 secs. If I launch the explain I have:

```
addr    opcode  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  comment
0   Init    0   27  0       0   
1   Integer 10000   1   0       0   
2   OpenRead    1   2   0   4   0   
3   OpenRead    0   2   0   4   0   
4   OpenRead    2   38110   0   k(2,,)  2   
5   Rewind  1   26  0       0   
6   Column  1   3   3       0   
7   Function    0   3   2   rev(1)  0   
8   IsNull  2   25  0       0   
9   Affinity    2   1   0   B   0   
10  SeekGE  2   25  2   1   0   
11  IdxGT   2   25  2   1   0   
12  DeferredSeek    2   0   0       0   
13  Column  2   0   4       64  
14  Function    0   4   3   length(1)   0   
15  Le  5   24  3       80  
16  Column  2   0   3       0   
17  Column  2   0   6       0   
18  Function    0   6   4   rev(1)  0   
19  Eq  4   24  3   BINARY-8    82  
20  Column  0   2   7       0   
21  Column  1   2   8       0   
22  ResultRow   7   2   0       0   
23  DecrJumpZero    1   26  0       0   
24  Next    2   11  1       0   
25  Next    1   6   0       1   
26  Halt    0   0   0       0   
27  Transaction 0   0   5   0   1   
28  Integer 3   5   0       0   
29  Goto    0   1   0       0
```

Row 11, IdxGT,it seems uses the index. Ok.

If I launch:

```
SELECT a.v originale,b.v contrario
FROM fdic a
INNER JOIN fdic b ON a.v=rev(b.v) 
WHERE length(a.v)>3 
AND a.v<>rev(a.v)
```

The condition in the `INNER JOIN` is not more `a.v_a` but `a.v` The column v is not indexed so I would expect an O(n^2) of 3M rows. But I have execution time 12 seconds.Ok is higher but I would expect days not seconds.
If I launch the EXPLAIN I have:

```
addr    opcode  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  comment
0   Init    0   40  0       0   
1   Integer 10000   1   0       0   
2   OpenRead    1   2   0   3   0   
3   OpenRead    0   2   0   4   0   
4   Rewind  1   39  0       0   
5   Once    0   19  0       0   
6   OpenAutoindex   2   3   0   k(3,B,,)    0   
7   Blob    10000   2   0       0   
8   Rewind  0   19  0       0   
9   Column  0   3   4       64  
10  Function    0   4   3   length(1)   0   
11  Le  5   18  3       80  
12  Column  0   2   6       0   
13  Column  0   3   7       0   
14  Rowid   0   8   0       0   
15  MakeRecord  6   3   3       0   
16  FilterAdd   2   0   6   1   0   
17  IdxInsert   2   3   0       16  
18  Next    0   9   0       3   
19  Column  1   2   3       0   
20  Function    0   3   9   rev(1)  0   
21  IsNull  9   38  0       0   
22  Affinity    9   1   0   B   0   
23  Filter  2   38  9   1   0   
24  SeekGE  2   38  9   1   0   
25  IdxGT   2   38  9   1   0   
26  Column  2   1   4       64  
27  Function    0   4   3   length(1)   0   
28  Le  5   37  3       80  
29  Column  2   1   3       0   
30  Column  2   1   10      0   
31  Function    0   10  4   rev(1)  0   
32  Eq  4   37  3   BINARY-8    82  
33  Column  2   0   11      0   
34  Column  1   2   12      0   
35  ResultRow   11  2   0       0   
36  DecrJumpZero    1   39  0       0   
37  Next    2   25  0       0   
38  Next    1   5   0       1   
39  Halt    0   0   0       0   
40  Transaction 0   0   5   0   1   
41  Integer 3   5   0       0   
42  Goto    0   1   0       0
```

Row 25 IdxGT. Where does this index come from?
So I need that somebody helps me to read these EXPLAIN.
**Is the second query using an index?**
**How can I get an O(n^2), to explain the indexes?**
**I'm very interested to the optimization that SQLite does to avoid this O(n^2), can somebody explain me what does it do?**
If you need the db to test it,  it's on-line, but I do not know if I can post the address, just ask in the comments  and I give you the address.

Comment: See section 14 of [sqlite's optimizer documentation](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html) with respect to autoindexing. Everything you asked is right there. As a side note: `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` is often much easier to understand than `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: wow: EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN is very usefull, just two rows. Yes there is an AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX. Now I'm going to read the guide. Thanks.

Comment: If this question has been answered, please close it to dequeue

Comment: How do I close it?